Header responsivo
espero que puedan ayudarme con un problema que estoy teniendo en mi proyecto. Estoy trabajando en un header (la parte superior de mi página web) que tiene un menú de navegación con enlaces (links). Para hacer que los enlaces se alinearan correctamente en el centro de la pantalla, decidí utilizar la propiedad de posición absoluta (position: absolute). Esto funcionó bien para centrar los enlaces, ya que antes no se alineaban correctamente con la pantalla.
Sin embargo, cuando intento hacer que el diseño sea responsivo (es decir, que se ajuste a diferentes tamaños de pantalla, como móviles y tabletas), el menú ya no se despliega correctamente. Lo que sucede es que los enlaces terminan posicionándose encima del logo, en lugar de estar en su lugar adecuado dentro del menú. Este comportamiento no es el que esperaba y me está causando problemas con la visualización en dispositivos más pequeños.
Agradecería mucho si alguien pudiera ayudarme a resolver este inconveniente. Me gustaría saber si hay alguna mejor forma de organizar la disposición de los enlaces y el logo para que, al hacer el diseño responsivo, todo se vea correctamente y sin que los enlaces se superpongan con otros elementos del header.
este es el código:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>DNX</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Vista/Css/Encabezado.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Vista/Css/ModalLogin.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Vista/Css/ModalRegistro.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amatic+SC:wght@400;700&family=Economica:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header id="header">
        <img class="logo" id="Lg" src="https://fontmeme.com/permalink/241121/b37e8d2a79bb0dcb8d7f8e1b712dfea5.png" alt="DNX Logo" border="0">
        <nav id="navMenu">       
            <ul class="link">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" aria-label="Hombre">HOMBRE</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="#" aria-label="Pantalon">Pantalon</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" aria-label="Camisa">Camisas/Camisetas</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" aria-label="Hoodie">Hoodie</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" aria-label="Mujer">MUJER</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="#" aria-label="Pantalon">Pantalon</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" aria-label="Camisa">Camisas/Camisetas</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" aria-label="Hoodie">Hoodie</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>   
                <li><a href="#" aria-label="Sale">SALE</a></li>
                <li id="loginMenuItem"><a href="#" aria-label="Login">Login</a></li> <!-- Nuevo elemento para Login -->
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="cta-container">
            <img class="Buscar" id="Buscador" src="/Vista/Img/Lupa.png" alt="Buscar">
            <span class="icon-text">Buscar</span>
            <img class="Perfil" id="openModal" src="/Vista/Img/Perfil.png" alt="Perfil">
            <span class="icon-text" id="loginText">Perfil</span>
            <img class="Carrito" id="cartIcon" src="/Vista/Img/Carrito.png" alt="Carrito">
            <span class="icon-text">Carrito</span>
        </div>
        <!-- Cambia el botón por una imagen -->
        <img id="menuButton" class="menu-button" src="/Vista/Img/Menu.png" alt="Menú" style="cursor: pointer;"> <!-- Reemplaza la ruta de la imagen -->
    </header>

    <!-- Segundo header para el buscador -->
    <header id="searchHeader" class="search-header">
        <div class="search-container">
            <input type="text" id="searchInput" placeholder="Buscar...">
            <img class="search-icon" src="/Vista/Img/Lupa.png" alt="Buscar">
        </div>
    </header>

    <!-- Contenedor para el modal -->
    <div id="modalContainer" class="modal-container"></div>

    <!-- Contenedor para el carrito -->
    <div id="cartContainer" class="cart-container">
        <h2>Carrito <span id="cartCount">(0)</span></h2> <!-- Agregamos un span para la cantidad -->
        <ul id="cartItems">
            <!-- Aquí se agregarán los elementos del carrito -->
        </ul>
        <div id="cartFooter">
            <button id="cartButton" class="cart-button">Ver todo</button> <!-- Cambiamos el p por un botón -->
        </div>
        <img class="close_car" id="closeCart" src="/Vista/Img/X.png" alt="X">
    </div>

    <div id="overlay" class="overlay"></div>
    <script src="/Vista/Script/Encabezado.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

li, a, button {
    font-weight: 500;
    color: black; /* Color de texto por defecto para enlaces */
    text-decoration: none;
}   

header {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px 50px;
    background-color: transparent; /* Fondo inicial transparente */
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease; /* Transición suave para el fondo */
    z-index: 1000;
}

header:hover,
header.header-hover {
    background-color: black; /* Cambiar fondo a negro al pasar el mouse o al activar el buscador */
}

header:hover li a,
header.header-hover li a,
header.header-hover .logo {
    color: white; /* Cambiar color de texto y logo a blanco al pasar el mouse o al activar el buscador */
}

header:hover .logo,
header.header-hover .logo {
    filter: brightness(1); /* Hacer que el logo se vuelva blanco al pasar el mouse o al activar el buscador */
}

header:hover .cta-container img,
header.header-hover .cta-container img {
    filter: brightness(0) invert(1); /* Cambia el color a blanco para los íconos */
}

.header-scrolled {
    background-color: black; /* Cambiar a negro al hacer scroll */
}

.header-scrolled li a,
.header-scrolled .logo {
    color: white; /* Cambiar color del texto y logo a blanco al hacer scroll */
    filter: brightness(1); /* Hacer que el logo se vuelva blanco al hacer scroll */
}

header.searchHeader-hover {
    background-color: black; /* Cambiar fondo a negro cuando el buscador está activo */
}

header.searchHeader-hover li a,
header.searchHeader-hover .logo {
    color: white; /* Cambiar color de texto y logo a blanco cuando el buscador está activo */
}

header.searchHeader-hover .cta-container img {
    filter: brightness(0) invert(1); /* Cambia el color a blanco para los íconos cuando el buscador está activo */
}

header.searchHeader-hover .logo {
    filter: brightness(1); /* Hacer que el logo se vuelva blanco cuando el buscador está activo */
}


.logo {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 5%;
    transition: filter 0.2s ease; /* Añadir transición al filtro del logo */
    filter: brightness(0); /* Hacer que el logo negro sea visible */
    margin: 0 auto;
    flex: 0 0 auto; /* No permitir que el logo crezca o se encoja */
}

nav {
    flex-grow: 1; /* Permitir que el nav ocupe el espacio disponible */
    display: flex; /* Usar flexbox para centrar el contenido */
    justify-content: center; /* Centrar horizontalmente */
}

.link {
    position: absolute; /* El contenido central se posiciona de forma absoluta */
    left: 50%; /* Posiciona el contenido en la mitad de la pantalla */
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Lo ajusta exactamente al centro de la pantalla */
    z-index: 1; /* Asegura que esté sobre otros elementos si es necesario */
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; /* Centrar los elementos de la lista */
    flex: 1;
    top: 50%;
}

.link li {
    padding: 0 13px;
    font-family: "Economica", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.link li a {
    transition: color 0.2s ease; /* Corregido el tiempo de transición */
}

.link li a:hover {
    color: rgb(214, 209, 209); /* Color al pasar el mouse sobre los enlaces */
}

.cta-container {
    display: flex; /* Asegurarse de que los íconos estén en línea */
    align-items: center; /* Centrar verticalmente los íconos */
    justify-content: flex-end; /* Alinear los íconos a la derecha */
    gap: 5px;
}

.cta-container img {
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: filter 0.2s ease; /* Añadir transición al filtro de los íconos */
}

.dropdown {
    display: none;
    position: absolute; /* Cambiar a relative */
    background-color: black;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 10px 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    margin-top: 10px; /* Agregar margen superior para evitar superposición */
}

.link li:hover .dropdown {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown li {
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

.dropdown li a {
    color: black; /* Color de texto en el dropdown */
    font-size: 15px;
}

.dropdown li a:hover {
    color: rgb(198, 198, 198); /* Color al pasar el mouse sobre los enlaces en el dropdown */
}

header:hover .logo {
    filter: brightness(1); /* Hacer que el logo se vuelva blanco al pasar el mouse sobre el encabezado */
}

header:hover .cta-container img {
    filter: brightness(0) invert(1); /* Cambia el color a blanco para los íconos */
}

/* Estilos para el contenido */
.content {
    margin-top: 80px; /* Espacio para el encabezado fijo */
    padding: 20px;
}

.search-header {
    top: 45px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; /* Centrar el contenido */
    align-items: center; /* Centrar verticalmente */
    padding: 10px 0; /* Espaciado superior e inferior */
    background-color: black; /* Fondo negro */
    position: relative; /* Para que se posicione correctamente bajo el header principal */
    z-index: 999; /* Asegurarse de que esté por encima de otros elementos */
    opacity: 0; /* Comienza invisible */
    transform: translateY(-20px); /* Comienza desplazado hacia arriba */
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease, transform 0.5s ease; /* Transiciones suaves */
}

.search-header.show {
    opacity: 1; /* Hacer visible */
    transform: translateY(0); /* Regresar a su posición original */
}

.search-container {
    position: relative; /* Para posicionar el ícono dentro del input */
}

#searchInput {
    width: 300px; /* Ancho del campo de búsqueda */
    padding: 10px 40px 10px 10px; /* Espaciado interno (derecha más grande para el ícono) */
    border: none; /* Sin borde */
    border-radius: 5px; /* Bordes redondeados */
    font-size: 16px; /* Tamaño de fuente */
}

.search-icon {
    position: absolute; /* Posicionar el ícono dentro del input */
    right: 10px; /* Espacio desde la derecha */
    top: 50%; /* Centrar verticalmente */
    transform: translateY(-50%); /* Ajustar para centrar */
    cursor: pointer; /* Cambiar cursor al pasar sobre el ícono */
    width: 20px; /* Ajustar el tamaño del ícono */
    height: 20px; /* Ajustar el tamaño del ícono */
}

.cart-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; /* Ajustar según la altura del header */
    right: -300px; /* Comenzar fuera de la vista */
    width: 300px; /* Ancho del carrito */
    height: 100%;
    bottom: 0; /* Altura del carrito */
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* Fondo negro para el carrito */
    color: white; /* Color de las letras del carrito */
    border: none; /* Borde del carrito */
    box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); /* Sombra para el carrito */
    z-index: 1002; /* Asegurarse de que esté por encima de otros elementos */
    padding: 20px; /* Espaciado interno */
    transition: right 0.3s ease; /* Transición suave para el movimiento */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; /* Para apilar los elementos verticalmente */
    justify-content: space-between; /* Espacio entre los elementos */
}

.cart-container.show {
    display: block; /* Mostrar el carrito */
    right: 0; /* Mover el carrito a la vista */
}

.cart-container h2 {
    font-family: "Economica", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: normal;
    cursor: pointer;}

.cart-container ul {
    list-style: none; /* Sin viñetas */
    padding: 0; /* Sin padding */
}

.cart-container li {
    margin: 5px 0; /* Espacio entre los elementos del carrito */
}

.close_car {
    background: none; /* Sin fondo */
    border: none; /* Sin borde */
    font-size: 10px; /* Tamaño de la X */
    cursor: pointer; /* Cambiar cursor al pasar sobre el botón */
    position: absolute; /* Posicionar en la esquina superior derecha */
    top: 25px;
    width: 20px; /* Ajusta el tamaño de la imagen según sea necesario */
    height: 20px; /* Ajusta el tamaño de la imagen según sea necesario */
    right: 20px; /* Espacio desde la derecha */
    transition: color 0.2s ease; /* Transición suave para el color */
    filter: brightness(0) invert(1); /* Cambia el color a blanco */
}

.close_car:hover {
    color: red; /* Cambiar color al pasar el mouse */
}

.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* Fondo negro semitransparente */
    display: none; /* Ocultar por defecto */
    z-index: 1001; /* Asegurarse de que esté por encima de otros elementos */
}

#cartFooter {
    margin-top: auto; /* Empuja el pie del carrito hacia abajo */
    display: flex; /* Usar flexbox para centrar el botón */
    justify-content: center; /* Centrar horizontalmente */
    padding: 10px 0; /* Espaciado superior e inferior */
}

.cart-button {
    background-color: #ffffff; /* Color de fondo del botón */
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* Color del texto */
    border: none; /* Sin borde */
    border-radius: 5px; /* Bordes redondeados */
    padding: 10px 20px; /* Espaciado interno */
    cursor: pointer; /* Cambiar cursor al pasar sobre el botón */
    font-size: 16px; /* Tamaño de fuente */
    width: 96%; /* Ancho del botón */
    transition: background-color 0.3s; /* Transición suave para el color de fondo */
}

.cart-button:hover {
    background-color: #dddddd; /* Color de fondo al pasar el mouse */
}

.cta-container img {
    display: inline; /* Asegúrate de que los íconos se muestren en línea */
}

.icon-text {
    display: none; /* Ocultar el texto por defecto */
    font-family: "Economica", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 20px;
}


header:hover span,
header.header-hover .span {
    color: white; /* Cambiar el color del texto a blanco al pasar el mouse sobre el header */
}

header:hover span img,
header.header-hover span img {
    filter: brightness(1); /* Asegurarse de que los íconos se vuelvan blancos al hacer hover */
}



.menu-button {
    display: none; /* Ocultar el botón de menú por defecto */
    background: none;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer; /* Cambiar cursor al pasar sobre el botón */
    transition: filter 0.2s ease; /* Añadir transición al filtro */
}

/* Cambiar el color de la imagen del botón de menú cuando el header es negro */
header.header-hover .menu-button,
.header-scrolled .menu-button {
    filter: brightness(0) invert(1); /* Cambiar a blanco */
}

/* Cambiar el color de la imagen del botón de menú cuando el header está en hover */
header:hover .menu-button {
    filter: brightness(0) invert(1); /* Cambiar a blanco */
}

#loginMenuItem {
    display: none; /* Ocultar el texto de Login en pantallas grandes */
}



@media (max-width: 768px) {

    .cta-container .Perfil,
    .cta-container .Login {
        display: none; /* Ocultar los íconos de perfil y login en pantallas pequeñas */
    }

    header {
        justify-content: center; /* Centrar todos los elementos en pantallas pequeñas */
        padding: 10px 20px; /* Ajustar el padding si es necesario */
    }

    nav {
        order: 1; /* Colocar el menú primero */
        flex: 1; /* Permitir que el nav ocupe el espacio disponible */
        display: flex; /* Asegurarse de que el nav use flexbox */
        justify-content: center; /* Centrar horizontalmente */
    }

    .logo {
        order: 2; /* Colocar el logo en el centro */
        margin: 0 auto; /* Centrar el logo */
        width: 80px;

    }

    .cta-container {
        order: 3; /* Colocar los íconos al final */
        justify-content: flex-end; /* Alinear a la derecha */
    }

    .menu-button {
        display: block; /* Mostrar el botón de menú en pantallas pequeñas */
        background-color: transparent;
        color: white;
        border: none;
        font-size: 30px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    /* El menú de navegación se oculta por defecto */
    #navMenu {
        display: none; /* El menú está oculto inicialmente */
        flex-direction: column; /* Los enlaces se apilan verticalmente */
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 55px; /* Asegúrate de que el menú esté debajo del header */
        left: 0;
        background-color: black;
        z-index: 1000; /* Asegurarse de que esté por encima de otros elementos */
        align-items: center; /* Centrar los elementos */
    }

    /* Mostrar el menú de navegación cuando se activa */
    #navMenu.show {
        display: flex;
    }

    .link {
        flex-direction: column; /* Cambiar la dirección de los enlaces a columna */
        align-items: center; /* Centrar los enlaces */
        padding: 0; /* Eliminar padding para que no afecte el centrado */
        position: static im; /* Eliminas el position: absolute */
        display: block; /* Los enlaces se muestran en bloque */
        text-align: center; /* Centra los enlaces en el contenedor */
        margin: 0; /* Elimina márgenes innecesarios */
        top: 100px;
    }

    .link li {
        flex-direction: column; /* Cambiar la dirección de los enlaces a columna */
        align-items: center; /* Centrar los enlaces */
        padding: 10px 0; /* Eliminar padding para que no afecte el centrado */
        position: static; /* Eliminas el position: absolute */
        display: block; /* Los enlaces se muestran en bloque */
        margin: 0;
        top: 0px;
    }

    .dropdown {
        position: relative; /* Cambiar a posición relativa en pantallas pequeñas */
        margin-top: 0; /* Eliminar margen superior para evitar superposición */
    }
    #loginMenuItem {
        display: block; /* Mostrar el texto de Login en el menú */
    }

}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const header = document.getElementById('header');
    const searchHeader = document.getElementById('searchHeader');
    const searchInput = document.getElementById('searchInput');
    const Buscador = document.getElementById('Buscador'); // Ícono que activa el buscador
    const cartIcon = document.getElementById('cartIcon'); // Ícono del carrito
    const cartContainer = document.getElementById('cartContainer'); // Contenedor del carrito
    const closeCartButton = document.getElementById('closeCart'); // Botón para cerrar el carrito
    const menuButton = document.getElementById('menuButton'); // Botón de menú
    const navMenu = document.getElementById('navMenu'); // Menú de navegación
    const linkList = document.querySelector('.link'); //
    
    // Ocultar el buscador al cargar la página
    if (searchHeader) {
        searchHeader.style 
        display = 'none';
    }

    // Cambia el fondo del encabezado al hacer scroll
    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
        header.classList.toggle('header-scrolled', window.scrollY > 10);
    });

    // Manejo del botón para abrir el modal de login
    const openModalButton = document.getElementById('openModal');
    const modalContainer = document.getElementById('modalContainer');

    if (openModalButton) {
        openModalButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            fetch('/Vista/Html/ModalLogin.html')
                .then(response => response.text())
                .then(data => {
                    modalContainer.innerHTML = data;

                    const closeModalButton = document.querySelector('.ModalLogin .close');

                    // Cerrar el modal al hacer clic en el botón de cerrar
                    if (closeModalButton) {
                        closeModalButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
                            modalContainer.innerHTML = ''; // Limpiar el contenido del modal
                        });
                    }

                    // Cerrar el modal al hacer clic en el fondo (overlay)
                    loginModal.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
                        if (event.target === loginModal) {
                            modalContainer.innerHTML = ''; // Limpiar el contenido del modal
                        }
                    });
                })
                .catch(error => console.error('Error al cargar el modal:', error));
        });
    }

    // Manejo del buscador
    Buscador.addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (!searchHeader.classList.contains('show')) {
            searchHeader.classList.add('show'); // Mostrar el header de búsqueda
            header.classList.add('searchHeader-hover'); // Agregar clase para cambiar el color del encabezado
        } else {
            searchHeader.classList.remove('show'); // Ocultar el header de búsqueda
            header.classList.remove('searchHeader-hover'); // Quitar clase para volver al color original
        }
    });

    // Manejo del carrito
    cartIcon.addEventListener('click', () => {
        cartContainer.classList.toggle('show'); // Alternar la clase 'show' para mostrar/ocultar el carrito
        header.classList.toggle('header-hover'); // Mantener el hover en el header
        overlay.style.display = cartContainer.classList.contains('show') ? 'block' : 'none'; // Mostrar/ocultar el overlay

        // Ocultar los dropdowns del header
        dropdowns.forEach(dropdown => {
            dropdown.style.display = cartContainer.classList.contains('show') ? 'none' : 'block'; // Ocultar/mostrar dropdowns
        });
    });

    // Cerrar el carrito al hacer clic en la imagen de cerrar
    closeCartButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        cartContainer.classList.remove('show'); // Ocultar el carrito
        header.classList.remove('header-hover'); // Quitar el hover del header
        overlay.style.display = 'none'; // Ocultar el overlay
    });

    // Cerrar el carrito al hacer clic fuera del carrito
    document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        // Verificar si el clic fue fuera del carrito y del ícono del carrito
        if (!cartContainer.contains(event.target) && !cartIcon.contains(event.target)) {
            cartContainer.classList.remove('show'); // Ocultar el carrito
            header.classList.remove('header-hover'); // Quitar el hover del header
            overlay.style.display = 'none'; // Ocultar el overlay
        }
    });
    // Manejo del botón de menú
    menuButton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        event.stopPropagation(); // Evitar que el clic en el botón cierre el menú inmediatamente
        navMenu.classList.toggle('show'); // Alternar la clase 'show' para mostrar/ocultar el menú
    });

    // Cerrar el menú al hacer clic fuera de él
    document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        if (!navMenu.contains(event.target) && navMenu.classList.contains('show')) {
            navMenu.classList.remove('show'); // Ocultar el menú
        }
    });

    // Manejo del clic en los enlaces del menú
    dropdownLinks.forEach(link => {
        link.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            event.stopPropagation(); // Evitar que el clic en el enlace cierre el menú
            const dropdown = link.nextElementSibling; // Obtener el dropdown correspondiente
            if (dropdown) {
                event.preventDefault(); // Evitar el comportamiento por defecto del enlace
                dropdown.classList.toggle('show'); // Alternar la visibilidad del dropdown
            }
        });
    });

    // Cerrar los dropdowns al hacer clic fuera de ellos
    document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        dropdownLinks.forEach(link => {
            const dropdown = link.nextElementSibling; // Obtener el dropdown correspondiente
            if (dropdown && !link.contains(event.target) && !dropdown.contains(event.target)) {
                dropdown.classList.remove('show'); // Ocultar el dropdown si se hace clic fuera
            }
        });
    });

    
        // Función para agregar un producto al carrito
        function addToCart() {
            itemsInCart++; // Incrementar el contador de productos
            updateCartDisplay(); // Actualizar la visualización del carrito
        }
    
        // Función para actualizar la visualización del carrito
        function updateCartDisplay() {
            cartCount.textContent = `(${itemsInCart})`; // Actualizar la cantidad en el carrito
            cartButton.textContent = itemsInCart > 0 ? 'Comprar' : 'Ver todo'; // Cambiar el texto del botón según la cantidad
        }

            // Asignar eventos de clic a los textos de los íconos
    document.getElementById('BuscadorLink').addEventListener('click', () => {
        // Lógica para buscar
        console.log('Buscar clicado');
    });

    document.getElementById('PerfilLink').addEventListener('click', () => {
        // Lógica para abrir el perfil
        console.log('Perfil clicado');
    });

    document.getElementById('CarritoLink').addEventListener('click', () => {
        // Lógica para abrir el carrito
        cartContainer.classList.toggle('show'); // Alternar la clase 'show' para mostrar/ocultar el carrito
        overlay.style.display = cartContainer.classList.contains('show') ? 'block' : 'none'; // Mostrar/ocultar el overlay
    });

    
});




Encuentro un tanto dificil ayudarte cuando no puedo ver el problema. Trata de realizar un [mre] para ayudar mejor. Realiza un código mínimo, con solo el header, repitiendo los pasos de los CSS, ya que hay 3 archivos CSS en ese html y no se si es todo el de abajo. Mismo caso con los JS.

También puedes centrar los enlaces con text-align: center  o con flexbox.

El código no está lo suficientemente completo como para mostrar el problema (lee sobre cómo crear un [mcve] y edita la pregunta). Sería ideal que añadieses imágenes de cómo se ve y cómo quieres que se vea.

Tus elementos se desplazan hacia arriba para aplicar el espacio que ocupan los enlaces del submenú. Para corregirlo tendrás que dar más espacio a estos elementos y que su despliegue se haga desplazando los elementos que tengan por debajo y no los que cargan por arriba, cambiando en "height" de que disponen.
Una solución alternativa que creo que resuelve de otro modo interesante el problema es colocando los elementos del submenú al lado cuando este se abre, dando la posibilidad de navegación sin scroll al usuario. Para ello he modificado levemente tu código a modo de ejemplo (comentado en CSS los apartados modificados). Podrás ver por los colores empleados como se identifica la sección en que te encuentras en todo momento.


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const header = document.getElementById('header');
    const searchHeader = document.getElementById('searchHeader');
    const searchInput = document.getElementById('searchInput');
    const Buscador = document.getElementById('Buscador'); // Ícono que activa el buscador
    const cartIcon = document.getElementById('cartIcon'); // Ícono del carrito
    const cartContainer = document.getElementById('cartContainer'); // Contenedor del carrito
    const closeCartButton = document.getElementById('closeCart'); // Botón para cerrar el carrito
    const menuButton = document.getElementById('menuButton'); // Botón de menú
    const navMenu = document.getElementById('navMenu'); // Menú de navegación
    const linkList = document.querySelector('.link'); //
    
    // Ocultar el buscador al cargar la página
    if (searchHeader) {
        searchHeader.style 
        display = 'none';
    }

    // Cambia el fondo del encabezado al hacer scroll
    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
        header.classList.toggle('header-scrolled', window.scrollY > 10);
    });

    // Manejo del botón para abrir el modal de login
    const openModalButton = document.getElementById('openModal');
    const modalContainer = document.getElementById('modalContainer');

    if (openModalButton) {
        openModalButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
            fetch('/Vista/Html/ModalLogin.html')
                .then(response => response.text())
                .then(data => {
                    modalContainer.innerHTML = data;

                    const closeModalButton = document.querySelector('.ModalLogin .close');

                    // Cerrar el modal al hacer clic en el botón de cerrar
                    if (closeModalButton) {
                        closeModalButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
                            modalContainer.innerHTML = ''; // Limpiar el contenido del modal
                        });
                    }

                    // Cerrar el modal al hacer clic en el fondo (overlay)
                    loginModal.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
                        if (event.target === loginModal) {
                            modalContainer.innerHTML = ''; // Limpiar el contenido del modal
                        }
                    });
                })
                .catch(error => console.error('Error al cargar el modal:', error));
        });
    }

    // Manejo del buscador
    Buscador.addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (!searchHeader.classList.contains('show')) {
            searchHeader.classList.add('show'); // Mostrar el header de búsqueda
            header.classList.add('searchHeader-hover'); // Agregar clase para cambiar el color del encabezado
        } else {
            searchHeader.classList.remove('show'); // Ocultar el header de búsqueda
            header.classList.remove('searchHeader-hover'); // Quitar clase para volver al color original
        }
    });

    // Manejo del carrito
    cartIcon.addEventListener('click', () => {
        cartContainer.classList.toggle('show'); // Alternar la clase 'show' para mostrar/ocultar el carrito
        header.classList.toggle('header-hover'); // Mantener el hover en el header
        overlay.style.display = cartContainer.classList.contains('show') ? 'block' : 'none'; // Mostrar/ocultar el overlay

        // Ocultar los dropdowns del header
        dropdowns.forEach(dropdown => {
            dropdown.style.display = cartContainer.classList.contains('show') ? 'none' : 'block'; // Ocultar/mostrar dropdowns
        });
    });

    // Cerrar el carrito al hacer clic en la imagen de cerrar
    closeCartButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        cartContainer.classList.remove('show'); // Ocultar el carrito
        header.classList.remove('header-hover'); // Quitar el hover del header
        overlay.style.display = 'none'; // Ocultar el overlay
    });

    // Cerrar el carrito al hacer clic fuera del carrito
    document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        // Verificar si el clic fue fuera del carrito y del ícono del carrito
        if (!cartContainer.contains(event.target) && !cartIcon.contains(event.target)) {
            cartContainer.classList.remove('show'); // Ocultar el carrito
            header.classList.remove('header-hover'); // Quitar el hover del header
            overlay.style.display = 'none'; // Ocultar el overlay
        }
    });
    // Manejo del botón de menú
    menuButton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        event.stopPropagation(); // Evitar que el clic en el botón cierre el menú inmediatamente
        navMenu.classList.toggle('show'); // Alternar la clase 'show' para mostrar/ocultar el menú
    });

    // Cerrar el menú al hacer clic fuera de él
    document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        if (!navMenu.contains(event.target) && navMenu.classList.contains('show')) {
            navMenu.classList.remove('show'); // Ocultar el menú
        }
    });

    // Manejo del clic en los enlaces del menú
    dropdownLinks.forEach(link => {
        link.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            event.stopPropagation(); // Evitar que el clic en el enlace cierre el menú
            const dropdown = link.nextElementSibling; // Obtener el dropdown correspondiente
            if (dropdown) {
                event.preventDefault(); // Evitar el comportamiento por defecto del enlace
                dropdown.classList.toggle('show'); // Alternar la visibilidad del dropdown
            }
        });
    });

    // Cerrar los dropdowns al hacer clic fuera de ellos
    document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        dropdownLinks.forEach(link => {
            const dropdown = link.nextElementSibling; // Obtener el dropdown correspondiente
            if (dropdown && !link.contains(event.target) && !dropdown.contains(event.target)) {
                dropdown.classList.remove('show'); // Ocultar el dropdown si se hace clic fuera
            }
        });
    });

    
        // Función para agregar un producto al carrito
        function addToCart() {
            itemsInCart++; // Incrementar el contador de productos
            updateCartDisplay(); // Actualizar la visualización del carrito
        }
    
        // Función para actualizar la visualización del carrito
        function updateCartDisplay() {
            cartCount.textContent = `(${itemsInCart})`; // Actualizar la cantidad en el carrito
            cartButton.textContent = itemsInCart > 0 ? 'Comprar' : 'Ver todo'; // Cambiar el texto del botón según la cantidad
        }

            // Asignar eventos de clic a los textos de los íconos
    document.getElementById('BuscadorLink').addEventListener('click', () => {
        // Lógica para buscar
        console.log('Buscar clicado');
    });

    document.getElementById('PerfilLink').addEventListener('click', () => {
        // Lógica para abrir el perfil
        console.log('Perfil clicado');
    });

    document.getElementById('CarritoLink').addEventListener('click', () => {
        // Lógica para abrir el carrito
        cartContainer.classList.toggle('show'); // Alternar la clase 'show' para mostrar/ocultar el carrito
        overlay.style.display = cartContainer.classList.contains('show') ? 'block' : 'none'; // Mostrar/ocultar el overlay
    });

    
});
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

li, a, button {
    font-weight: 500;
    color: black; /* Color de texto por defecto para enlaces */
    text-decoration: none;
}   

header {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px 50px;
    background-color: transparent; /* Fondo inicial transparente */
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease; /* Transición suave para el fondo */
    z-index: 1000;
}

header:hover,
header.header-hover {
    background-color: black; /* Cambiar fondo a negro al pasar el mouse o al activar el buscador */
}

header:hover li a,
header.header-hover li a,
header.header-hover .logo {
    color: white; /* Cambiar color de texto y logo a blanco al pasar el mouse o al activar el buscador */
}

header:hover .logo,
header.header-hover .logo {
    filter: brightness(1); /* Hacer que el logo se vuelva blanco al pasar el mouse o al activar el buscador */
}

header:hover .cta-container img,
header.header-hover .cta-container img {
    filter: brightness(0) invert(1); /* Cambia el color a blanco para los íconos */
}

.header-scrolled {
    background-color: black; /* Cambiar a negro al hacer scroll */
}

.header-scrolled li a,
.header-scrolled .logo {
    color: white; /* Cambiar color del texto y logo a blanco al hacer scroll */
    filter: brightness(1); /* Hacer que el logo se vuelva blanco al hacer scroll */
}

header.searchHeader-hover {
    background-color: black; /* Cambiar fondo a negro cuando el buscador está activo */
}

header.searchHeader-hover li a,
header.searchHeader-hover .logo {
    color: white; /* Cambiar color de texto y logo a blanco cuando el buscador está activo */
}

header.searchHeader-hover .cta-container img {
    filter: brightness(0) invert(1); /* Cambia el color a blanco para los íconos cuando el buscador está activo */
}

header.searchHeader-hover .logo {
    filter: brightness(1); /* Hacer que el logo se vuelva blanco cuando el buscador está activo */
}


.logo {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 5%;
    transition: filter 0.2s ease; /* Añadir transición al filtro del logo */
    filter: brightness(0); /* Hacer que el logo negro sea visible */
    margin: 0 auto;
    flex: 0 0 auto; /* No permitir que el logo crezca o se encoja */
}

nav {
    flex-grow: 1; /* Permitir que el nav ocupe el espacio disponible */
    display: flex; /* Usar flexbox para centrar el contenido */
    justify-content: center; /* Centrar horizontalmente */
}

.link {
    position: absolute; /* El contenido central se posiciona de forma absoluta */
    left: 50%; /* Posiciona el contenido en la mitad de la pantalla */
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Lo ajusta exactamente al centro de la pantalla */
    z-index: 1; /* Asegura que esté sobre otros elementos si es necesario */
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; /* Centrar los elementos de la lista */
    flex: 1;
    top: 50%;
}

.link li {
    padding: 0 13px;
    font-family: "Economica", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.link li a {
    transition: color 0.2s ease; /* Corregido el tiempo de transición */
}

.link li a:hover {
    color: rgb(214, 209, 209); /* Color al pasar el mouse sobre los enlaces */
}

.cta-container {
    display: flex; /* Asegurarse de que los íconos estén en línea */
    align-items: center; /* Centrar verticalmente los íconos */
    justify-content: flex-end; /* Alinear los íconos a la derecha */
    gap: 5px;
}

.cta-container img {
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: filter 0.2s ease; /* Añadir transición al filtro de los íconos */
}

.dropdown {
    display: none;
    position: absolute; /* Cambiar a relative */
    background-color: black;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 10px 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    margin-top: 10px; /* Agregar margen superior para evitar superposición */
}

.link li:hover .dropdown {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown li {
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

.dropdown li a {
    color: black; /* Color de texto en el dropdown */
    font-size: 15px;
}

.dropdown li a:hover {
    color: rgb(198, 198, 198); /* Color al pasar el mouse sobre los enlaces en el dropdown */
}

header:hover .logo {
    filter: brightness(1); /* Hacer que el logo se vuelva blanco al pasar el mouse sobre el encabezado */
}

header:hover .cta-container img {
    filter: brightness(0) invert(1); /* Cambia el color a blanco para los íconos */
}

/* Estilos para el contenido */
.content {
    margin-top: 80px; /* Espacio para el encabezado fijo */
    padding: 20px;
}

.search-header {
    top: 45px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; /* Centrar el contenido */
    align-items: center; /* Centrar verticalmente */
    padding: 10px 0; /* Espaciado superior e inferior */
    background-color: black; /* Fondo negro */
    position: relative; /* Para que se posicione correctamente bajo el header principal */
    z-index: 999; /* Asegurarse de que esté por encima de otros elementos */
    opacity: 0; /* Comienza invisible */
    transform: translateY(-20px); /* Comienza desplazado hacia arriba */
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease, transform 0.5s ease; /* Transiciones suaves */
}

.search-header.show {
    opacity: 1; /* Hacer visible */
    transform: translateY(0); /* Regresar a su posición original */
}

.search-container {
    position: relative; /* Para posicionar el ícono dentro del input */
}

#searchInput {
    width: 300px; /* Ancho del campo de búsqueda */
    padding: 10px 40px 10px 10px; /* Espaciado interno (derecha más grande para el ícono) */
    border: none; /* Sin borde */
    border-radius: 5px; /* Bordes redondeados */
    font-size: 16px; /* Tamaño de fuente */
}

.search-icon {
    position: absolute; /* Posicionar el ícono dentro del input */
    right: 10px; /* Espacio desde la derecha */
    top: 50%; /* Centrar verticalmente */
    transform: translateY(-50%); /* Ajustar para centrar */
    cursor: pointer; /* Cambiar cursor al pasar sobre el ícono */
    width: 20px; /* Ajustar el tamaño del ícono */
    height: 20px; /* Ajustar el tamaño del ícono */
}

.cart-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; /* Ajustar según la altura del header */
    right: -300px; /* Comenzar fuera de la vista */
    width: 300px; /* Ancho del carrito */
    height: 100%;
    bottom: 0; /* Altura del carrito */
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* Fondo negro para el carrito */
    color: white; /* Color de las letras del carrito */
    border: none; /* Borde del carrito */
    box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); /* Sombra para el carrito */
    z-index: 1002; /* Asegurarse de que esté por encima de otros elementos */
    padding: 20px; /* Espaciado interno */
    transition: right 0.3s ease; /* Transición suave para el movimiento */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; /* Para apilar los elementos verticalmente */
    justify-content: space-between; /* Espacio entre los elementos */
}

.cart-container.show {
    display: block; /* Mostrar el carrito */
    right: 0; /* Mover el carrito a la vista */
}

.cart-container h2 {
    font-family: "Economica", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: normal;
    cursor: pointer;}

.cart-container ul {
    list-style: none; /* Sin viñetas */
    padding: 0; /* Sin padding */
}

.cart-container li {
    margin: 5px 0; /* Espacio entre los elementos del carrito */
}

.close_car {
    background: none; /* Sin fondo */
    border: none; /* Sin borde */
    font-size: 10px; /* Tamaño de la X */
    cursor: pointer; /* Cambiar cursor al pasar sobre el botón */
    position: absolute; /* Posicionar en la esquina superior derecha */
    top: 25px;
    width: 20px; /* Ajusta el tamaño de la imagen según sea necesario */
    height: 20px; /* Ajusta el tamaño de la imagen según sea necesario */
    right: 20px; /* Espacio desde la derecha */
    transition: color 0.2s ease; /* Transición suave para el color */
    filter: brightness(0) invert(1); /* Cambia el color a blanco */
}

.close_car:hover {
    color: red; /* Cambiar color al pasar el mouse */
}

.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* Fondo negro semitransparente */
    display: none; /* Ocultar por defecto */
    z-index: 1001; /* Asegurarse de que esté por encima de otros elementos */
}

#cartFooter {
    margin-top: auto; /* Empuja el pie del carrito hacia abajo */
    display: flex; /* Usar flexbox para centrar el botón */
    justify-content: center; /* Centrar horizontalmente */
    padding: 10px 0; /* Espaciado superior e inferior */
}

.cart-button {
    background-color: #ffffff; /* Color de fondo del botón */
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* Color del texto */
    border: none; /* Sin borde */
    border-radius: 5px; /* Bordes redondeados */
    padding: 10px 20px; /* Espaciado interno */
    cursor: pointer; /* Cambiar cursor al pasar sobre el botón */
    font-size: 16px; /* Tamaño de fuente */
    width: 96%; /* Ancho del botón */
    transition: background-color 0.3s; /* Transición suave para el color de fondo */
}

.cart-button:hover {
    background-color: #dddddd; /* Color de fondo al pasar el mouse */
}

.cta-container img {
    display: inline; /* Asegúrate de que los íconos se muestren en línea */
}

.icon-text {
    display: none; /* Ocultar el texto por defecto */
    font-family: "Economica", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 20px;
}


header:hover span,
header.header-hover .span {
    color: white; /* Cambiar el color del texto a blanco al pasar el mouse sobre el header */
}

header:hover span img,
header.header-hover span img {
    filter: brightness(1); /* Asegurarse de que los íconos se vuelvan blancos al hacer hover */
}



.menu-button {
    display: none; /* Ocultar el botón de menú por defecto */
    background: none;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer; /* Cambiar cursor al pasar sobre el botón */
    transition: filter 0.2s ease; /* Añadir transición al filtro */
}

/* Cambiar el color de la imagen del botón de menú cuando el header es negro */
header.header-hover .menu-button,
.header-scrolled .menu-button {
    filter: brightness(0) invert(1); /* Cambiar a blanco */
}

/* Cambiar el color de la imagen del botón de menú cuando el header está en hover */
header:hover .menu-button {
    filter: brightness(0) invert(1); /* Cambiar a blanco */
}

#loginMenuItem {
    display: none; /* Ocultar el texto de Login en pantallas grandes */
}



@media (max-width: 768px) {

    .cta-container .Perfil,
    .cta-container .Login {
        display: none; /* Ocultar los íconos de perfil y login en pantallas pequeñas */
    }

    header {
        justify-content: center; /* Centrar todos los elementos en pantallas pequeñas */
        padding: 10px 20px; /* Ajustar el padding si es necesario */
    }

    nav {
        order: 1; /* Colocar el menú primero */
        flex: 1; /* Permitir que el nav ocupe el espacio disponible */
        display: flex; /* Asegurarse de que el nav use flexbox */
        justify-content: center; /* Centrar horizontalmente */
    }

    .logo {
        order: 2; /* Colocar el logo en el centro */
        margin: 0 auto; /* Centrar el logo */
        width: 80px;

    }

    .cta-container {
        order: 3; /* Colocar los íconos al final */
        justify-content: flex-end; /* Alinear a la derecha */
    }

    .menu-button {
        display: block; /* Mostrar el botón de menú en pantallas pequeñas */
        background-color: transparent;
        color: white;
        border: none;
        font-size: 30px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    /* El menú de navegación se oculta por defecto */
    #navMenu {
        display: none; /* El menú está oculto inicialmente */
        flex-direction: column; /* Los enlaces se apilan verticalmente */
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 55px; /* Asegúrate de que el menú esté debajo del header */
        left: 0;
        background-color: black;
        z-index: 1000; /* Asegurarse de que esté por encima de otros elementos */
        align-items: center; /* Centrar los elementos */
    }

    /* Mostrar el menú de navegación cuando se activa */
    #navMenu.show {
        display: flex;
    }

    .link {
        flex-direction: column; /* Cambiar la dirección de los enlaces a columna */
        align-items: center; /* Centrar los enlaces */
        padding: 0; /* Eliminar padding para que no afecte el centrado */
        position: static im; /* Eliminas el position: absolute */
        display: block; /* Los enlaces se muestran en bloque */
        text-align: center; /* Centra los enlaces en el contenedor */
        margin: 0; /* Elimina márgenes innecesarios */
        top: 90px;
    }

    .link li {
        flex-direction: column; /* Cambiar la dirección de los enlaces a columna */
        align-items: center; /* Centrar los enlaces */
        padding: 10px 0; /* Eliminar padding para que no afecte el centrado */
        position: static; /* Eliminas el position: absolute */
        display: block; /* Los enlaces se muestran en bloque */
        margin: 0;
        top: 0px;
    }
    
    
    /* INICIO código editado para el ejemplo de menu */

    .dropdown {
        position: absolute; /* Cambiada a posición absolute para fijar el elemento en lugar deseado y que desplazamiento se controle desde esta nueva posición  */
        top: 0; /*fijamos elmento en la posición top del contenedor */
        left: 55px; /* desplazamos el submenú lateralmente */
        margin-top: 0; /* Eliminar margen superior para evitar superposición */
    }
    
    #navMenu ul li:nth-child(2) li a{
color: blue
}
    
    header:hover li a.EnlaceSeccion {color:red; position: relative;}
    /* FIN código editado para el ejemplo de menu */
    
    #loginMenuItem {
        display: block; /* Mostrar el texto de Login en el menú */
    }
    
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>DNX</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Vista/Css/Encabezado.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Vista/Css/ModalLogin.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Vista/Css/ModalRegistro.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Amatic+SC:wght@400;700&family=Economica:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header id="header">
        <img class="logo" id="Lg" src="https://fontmeme.com/permalink/241121/b37e8d2a79bb0dcb8d7f8e1b712dfea5.png" alt="DNX Logo" border="0">
        <nav id="navMenu">       
            <ul class="link">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="EnlaceSeccion" aria-label="Hombre">HOMBRE</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="#" aria-label="Pantalon">Pantalon</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" aria-label="Camisa">Camisas/Camisetas</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" aria-label="Hoodie">Hoodie</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="EnlaceSeccion" aria-label="Mujer">MUJER</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="#" aria-label="Pantalon">Pantalon</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" aria-label="Camisa">Camisas/Camisetas</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" aria-label="Hoodie">Hoodie</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>   
                <li><a href="#" class="EnlaceSeccion" aria-label="Sale">SALE</a></li>
                <li id="loginMenuItem"><a href="#" class="EnlaceSeccion" aria-label="Login">Login</a></li> <!-- Nuevo elemento para Login -->
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="cta-container">
            <img class="Buscar" id="Buscador" src="/Vista/Img/Lupa.png" alt="Buscar">
            <span class="icon-text">Buscar</span>
            <img class="Perfil" id="openModal" src="/Vista/Img/Perfil.png" alt="Perfil">
            <span class="icon-text" id="loginText">Perfil</span>
            <img class="Carrito" id="cartIcon" src="/Vista/Img/Carrito.png" alt="Carrito">
            <span class="icon-text">Carrito</span>
        </div>
        <!-- Cambia el botón por una imagen -->
        <img id="menuButton" class="menu-button" src="/Vista/Img/Menu.png" alt="Menú" style="cursor: pointer;"> <!-- Reemplaza la ruta de la imagen -->
    </header>

    <!-- Segundo header para el buscador -->
    <header id="searchHeader" class="search-header">
        <div class="search-container">
            <input type="text" id="searchInput" placeholder="Buscar...">
            <img class="search-icon" src="/Vista/Img/Lupa.png" alt="Buscar">
        </div>
    </header>

    <!-- Contenedor para el modal -->
    <div id="modalContainer" class="modal-container"></div>

    <!-- Contenedor para el carrito -->
    <div id="cartContainer" class="cart-container">
        <h2>Carrito <span id="cartCount">(0)</span></h2> <!-- Agregamos un span para la cantidad -->
        <ul id="cartItems">
            <!-- Aquí se agregarán los elementos del carrito -->
        </ul>
        <div id="cartFooter">
            <button id="cartButton" class="cart-button">Ver todo</button> <!-- Cambiamos el p por un botón -->
        </div>
        <img class="close_car" id="closeCart" src="/Vista/Img/X.png" alt="X">
    </div>

    <div id="overlay" class="overlay"></div>
    <script src="/Vista/Script/Encabezado.js"></script>
</body>
</html>



